# Why don't the bytes intersect?

Tags: assembly, gdb

Why don't the bytes intersect??

```
(gdb) x/4x 0x7fffffffe958
0x7fffffffe958: 0x0040045c  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
(gdb) x/4x 0x7fffffffe960
0x7fffffffe960: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0xf401d994  0x00000034
```

Comment: Logically,bytes after `0x7fffffffe958` should intersect with those after `0x7fffffffe960`,right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They do. It looks like you're forgetting that the address is in hex though. Here are the dwords from above, but with last two digits of the address of each byte below that byte's data:

```
0x0040045c  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
  58595a5b    5c5d5e5f    60616263    64656667

0x00000000  0x00000000  0xf401d994  0x00000034
  60616263    64656667    68696a6b    6c6d6e6f
```

If we match up the addresses, we see that bytes 0x60 through 0x67 are identical between the two (all zeros in both cases).